# Configuring a Jenkins pipeline to ignore building unchanged projects

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline that is triggered by a bitbucket webhook every time a pull request is created, and builds docker images.
My bitbucket repository contains multiple projects, each with it's own subfolder and Dockerfile.
I wouldn't want the pipeline to build docker images for all projects every time it is triggered.
How do I tell the pipeline to only build docker images for those projects that have changed?

Thanks,
O.

Comment: Are you using maven?

Comment: No, I am not using Maven.